# setState an array of JSX elements?

Tags: reactjs, components, jsx

In my function component, I have an array of `<div>` I have created using the response of an axios call.

I want to render those divs in the `return()` function. It's important they stay as `<div>`s.

This attempt does not seem to work. I get an error about the array not being an appropriate child item of React.

```
      const [firstNames, setFirstNames] = setState([])
      ....
      let firstNamesArray = JSON.parse(response.data.first_names)
      let newArr = []

      firstNamesArray.forEach(element => newArr.push(<div>{element}</div>));
      setFirstNames(newArr)

      ....
      return (
         {firstNames}
      }
```

Is there a way to render an array of s or other JSX elements in one variable like in the example above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it'd be *technically possible* to return just the array of the JSX elements:

```
return firstNames;
```

State should not be composed of JSX elements. Instead, set the `first_names` array (of strings?) into state, then map the state to `<div>`s only when rendering:

```
setFirstNames(JSON.parse(response.data.first_names));
```

```
// choose some appropriate key here...
return firstNames.map((name, i) => <div key={i}>{name}</div>);
```

Comment: What if it's an array of objects? How would I be able to parse the objects appropriate in the `return()` function?

Comment: Depends how you want to display the objects. Eg, if it's an object with `{ first: string, last: string }` you could do something like `=> <div>{name.first + ' ' + name.last}</div>`

Comment: But how do I get it to object form within the `return()` function? It seems I can't place an array of objects in `setFirstNames()`. I can only set it to a string.

Comment: When I try to do `setFirstNames(JSON.parse(response.data.first_names));`, I get `Error: Objects are not valid as a React child`

Comment: Sure you can have state be an array of objects..? There's absolutely nothing wrong with something like `const [names, setNames] = useState([]); ... setNames(response.names)` where `names` is an array of objects

Comment: I'm not sure where this `Error: Objects are not valid as a React child` is coming from then

Comment: That's a *rendering* error, not a state setting error. You need to look at the response body to figure out how you want to display it. You can't render *plain objects*, you need to navigate the objects to figure out how you want them to be rendered - eg `<div>{name.first + ' ' + name.last}</div>`

Answer (score 1):

```js
const firstNamesArray = JSON.parse(response.data.first_names)

return firstNamesArray.map((element, index) => (<div key={index}>{element}</div>))
```